# Updating height of async loaded images

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I wanna get like this:

[image]

I am using a custom `UITableViewCell` where I download images asynchronously with Alamofire **from within the cell**.

The images appear after the cell was loaded from within the `UITableviewController`.

Some images do not exist. So the cell should be collapsed and show only text if there is no image present.

How can I achieve to resize the cell when the image is present?
(All images should appear in the same height and full width.

What I already tried is something like this in my TableViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

But the result is pretty ugly:

[image]

Comment: If you want to resize cells when the image is retrieved, rather than just updating the image view asynchronously, you should instead update your image cache and then reload the row associated with that cell with [`reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows), at which point you can update the image view's image directly, rather than asynchronously.

Comment: So the `reloadRows` method should be placed in my `Viewcontroller` into the `cellForRowAt indexPath:` method? But how does the ViewController knows that the call within the cell is processed, to reload the Cell? My fetch method is IN the Cell class itself.